# Integer programming - multi-set partitioning

Tags: linear-programming, integer-programming

I'm trying to solve this question:

Let S be a multi-set of n integers, can S be partitioned into two sub-multi-sets $S1$,$S2$, such that: $$ \sum_{x \in S1} x = \sum_{y \in S2} y $$

I'm trying to figure out how the answer should look like. I know I need a function $$ \sum_{i=1}^m CiXi$$ but I'm not sure how maximizing \ minimizing it would help. Also, I guess I should have constraints on $Xi$ but don't know what constraints they should be (I know they are integers). Can you pls point me in the right direction?

Comment: I'm not so familiar with multi-sets. Looking at the definition, it seems at least not true when $S$ contains a single integer.

Comment: Obviously that can't be done in 1 integer set. In the decision problem, given a multi-set I need to decide if it has a partitioning. Here, given there is at least one, I guess I need to find the max partitioning

Comment: $S$ has a finite number of elements?

Comment: Yes. forgot to mention. S has n integers. Will add it to the question

Comment: Also, I imagine that your real question is not to decide if there exists a partition. This is pretty simple using a basic algorithm looping on all partitions, but to find an efficient algorithm.

Comment: I am not asking about the decision problem. I'm asking how the max-integer-problem should look like

Comment: If the sum of elements of $S$ is odd, then this cannot be done. Even if the sum is even, this is rarely true.

Comment: I know that. But this is a well known problem, and there is an IP form for it, and that's what I'm looking for. Not saying any set can be partitioned, but those who can, can be done with IP